# Initialize Objects as Class Members in C++

Tags: c++, oop

There are three classes.The first is a template, the second acts as generic for template and third implements the template.

```
template <class T>
class Shape {
T val,val_new;
public:
Shape(T initval)
{
   val=initval;
}
   ...
};


class TwoPoint
{
int width;
int value;
public:
TwoPoint()
{
  value=0;
  width=0;
}
TwoPoint(int v, int w)
{
  value=v;
  width=w;
}
 TwoPoint(const TwoPoint& t)
{
  value= t.value;
  width= t.width;
}
    ...
};





 class Rectangle
 {
  private:
   Shape<TwoPoint> val;
   TwoPoint newval;
  public:
 Rectangle(TwoPoint i)
  : val (Shape<TwoPoint> (i)) {}     
    ....
  };
```

I want to initialize the Rectangle and solidShape in some other class as class members and that can be done in java like:

```
  Rectangle r = new Rectangle(new TwoPoint(0,8));
  Shape<TwoPoint> solidShape = new Shape<TwoPoint>(new TwoPoint(0,5));
```

How can i do a similar type of thing in C++? I want to create an implementation like:

```
 class C
 {
  public:
  // initialize Rectangle here;
  // initialize solidShape here;
 }
```

The integer values shown here are just for illustration and can be anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to have a conversion constructor in C++ is through a const reference:

```
 Rectangle(const TwoPoint& i)
```

This also means you can pass a temporary as parameter:

```
 Rectangle* r = new Rectangle( TwoPoint(0,8) ); //dynamic storage
```

or

```
 Rectangle r( TwoPoint(0,8) ); //automatic storage
```

It would also work with a pass by value, but this is the standard way of doing it.

Same goes for the `Shape` class:

```
 Shape(const T& initval) //conversion constructor
```

and:

```
 Shape<TwoPoint>* solidShape = new Shape<TwoPoint>( TwoPoint(0,5) ); //dynamic storage
```

or

```
 Shape<TwoPoint> solidShape( TwoPoint(0,5) ); //automatic storage
```

In C++, `new` returns a pointer. But your conversion constructors take objects (not pointers to objects) by reference or value. So you need an object passed as parameter, not pointers.

#### If these two are class members:

- if you chose to have pointers, you need to free the memory in the destructor.
- if you chose automatic storage objects (what you have now), the destructors will be called when the containing object is destroyed, so you don't manually free the memory. To initialize automatic storage objects that are class members, you need to use an **initialization list**:

Like this:

```
class C
 {
    Shape<TwoPoint> solidShape;
    Rectangle r;
 public:
     C() : solidShape(TwoPoint(0,5)), r( TwoPoint(0,8) )  {} //initialization list in constructor    
 };
```

Comment: `Rectangle r = new Rectangle( TwoPoint(0,8) );` is not working

Comment: New returns a pointer as he just said - he forgot to make those pointer types,.  Should be Rectangle* ...or just non pointer Rectangle r(params);

Comment: @Luchian Grigore `new Rectangle ...` create a pointer and is not possible to assign to a Rectangle objetc. Besides, it's not a temporary variable, is heap allocated and memory leaked.

Comment: @TioPepe I had already edited the answer. It was a copy/paste error.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Sorry, I didn't saw it. I'm retracted ;-)

Comment: None of these methods are working.. Can u please copy and edit the classes and post the code

Comment: Rectangle is not in main(), but it is a class member.. and why do we need header files <map> and <string>

Comment: @user I already showed you how to handle class members at the end of my post.

Comment: why do we need header files <map> and <string>

Comment: @user you don't, those were residual headers that were already in my project when I compiled this. Did it work?

Comment: yes it did.. what statement do we use in C++ to exit from an infinite loop except break (like System.exit(0) in Java)

Comment: @user `exit(0)` but that terminates the program.

Answer (score 0):

We use const references as constructor parameters and initialization constructor chain:

```
template <class T>
class Shape {
    T val,val_new;
    public:
    Shape(const T & initval) :
        val(initval)
    {   
    }
    ...
};

class TwoPoint
{
    int width;
    int value;
    public:
    TwoPoint() :
        value(0),
        width(0)
    {
    }
    TwoPoint(int v, int w) :
        value(v),
        width(v)
    {
    }
    TwoPoint(const TwoPoint& t)
        value(t.value),
        width(t.width)
    {
    }
    ...
};

class Rectangle
{
    private:
        Shape<TwoPoint> val;
        TwoPoint newval;
    public:
        Rectangle(const TwoPoint & i)
        : val (Shape<TwoPoint> (i)) 
    {}     
     ....
};
```

and you create object like this:

```
TwoPoint t(0,8)
Rectangle r(t);
Shape<TwoPoint> shape(t);
```